# Create new partition like windows with rest free space in ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, 20.04, system-installation, usb-installation

I was installing Ubuntu 20.04 with something else option in the installation. I have a 500GB of hard disk, The problem is I have used `/`, `home`, `swap` but still I got some free space left. I want to create two partition or driver like windows, How can I create those partition here with this free space.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, just click the `+` on the left and select `ext4`. You can do this anytime after installation or before, doesn't matter when to add or remove additional partition(s). Please be aware it takes a complicated process to modify `/` and/or `/home` after installation.

Comment: If your reasoning for creating these partitions are for *organization*, reconsider your plans. Partitions are rigid and inflexible. Once they are set up and you have added data, they are very difficult to readjust. Essentially you are creating strict and arbitrary limitations on how you can use the available space on your disk.  Use folders for organization! The partitions are going to be mounted as folders anyway.  Also, a separate `/home` is not as useful as you think unless you are very adept at solving problems with configs if/when you choose to reuse `/home` on another install

Comment: As above but there's more, unfortunately. Partitioning is often down to personal preferences but there are some obvious flaws in yours: (1) A ESP of 1GB is a ridiculous waste of space especially if for a single OS; 100MB is more than enough. (2) **The ESP must be FAT32**. (2) There's no need for a swap partition, Ubuntu now uses swapfile by default and in any case, unless you intend to enable hibernation (not default and NOT recommended) and you have ~32GB RAM, making that size is, again, ridiculous. (3) A `/` of ~70GB with `/home` as a separated partition is, again, wasted space (...)

Comment: (4) A separated `/home` of only 100GB with so much space still available seem unwise and if you intend to save movies and/or install Steam games, definitely foolish. Lastly (5) **Why can't you create additional partitions?** Letting aside the fact that is likely nonsense as commented before, if you really can't create more than 4 that means you're using the old MBR ("msdos") partitioning where you definitely shouldn't. Use only GPT for NVMe drives. Conclusions: It seems you're trying to apply suggestions from 20 years ago.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation, I found this is the easiest way to install Linux as a single OS. It would be more helpful if anyone can share some source link about Linux disk management with installation. Or the best possible way to do it.

Comment: Advantages of gpt. https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Partitioning#Choosing_between_GPT_and_MBR UEFI/gpt partitioning in Advance, new versions use swap file so swap partition optional:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu I do not save large media files, but photos of grandkids is growing. I use a large data partition for those. I also like to have multiple / (root) partitions so I can experiment with settings or see next version before converting fully to next LTS  from main working install LTS install.

Comment: *"the best possible way"* - the best way is what works for you. That being said, consider my last comment to understand how some actions don't really help and can actually make things harder for you. The default installation uses a single partition for everything in the operating system. This is what works best for the overwhelming majority of people. Unless you have a very specific need to create some other partitions, don't make up a reason to do so. If you're new to Linux, what's best for you, is probably what's best for everyone else: use the guided installation's default settings.

Comment: If you're looking for guidance online about this particular topic you are probably going to overcomplicate everything. Lots of information online is outdated, lots of information will be about specific use cases that don't apply to you, and lots of information is just bad advice. The default settings are the default for a reason. If you don't have clear good reasons to change them, then you shouldn't. Going "against the grain" is probably one of the biggest mistakes a new Linux/Ubuntu user can make.